# are there any good tutorials/guides for UDP servers with netty?

Tags: java, server, udp, netty

I am trying to implement a Gameserver for my libgdx (java) game. I decided to go for UDP because it might not matter if a keystroke packet gets lost when there are 60 send per second. I read through the guide on the netty page but to me it seems like a TCP guide. So is there any guide for a UDP server? I would identify the sender by a UUID, so I don't need a channel context (TCP) I guess?! Is this the way to go? Thx in advance

Comment: Read the Help pages before posting here. Your Question is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: I've read some examples in the book "Netty in actions" regarding UDP. BTW, I'm going to build the small game on the same technologies (libgdx and Netty) :) But maybe I will take golang instead of Netty (I use Netty at my work), idk.

Comment: And, as far as I know, you have to use the same Netty API (for UDP, TCP or even synchronious TCP - it doesn't matter), so basically you have to change server's channel type only (in Bootstrap) from `.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)` to `NioDatagramChannel`, maybe Netty API will a little bit different (but not much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a higher level framework for your project, such as Vert.X, Micronout, Quarkus, gRPC Java etc. These frameworks are implemented on top of Netty and makes it easier to use Netty. I also recommend you to keep it simple, go with TPC if that is easier. Choose simplicity and implementation speed over performance at the early stages of these kinds of projects.

Comment: in fact i decided to go for networking without any frameworks. this is a learning project after all and i could use netty or something like that (using netty at work too) but i want to try to make it as lightweight as possible and it feels like just using DatagramSockets is the way to go then. I will try to implement the client-server architecture with client prediction and server conciliation in mind. Thx for that answer tho, that might help someone coming here from google.